# Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_kx^k$ be a polynomial with real coefficients

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this problem that says:

> Let $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k x^k$ be a polynomial with real coefficients,where $c_0 > 0$and $c_n < 0$. Then which of the following options is correct?
>
> 1. $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$
> 2. $f(x)<0$ for all $x<0$
> 3. $f(x)=0$ for some $x>0$
> 4. $f(x)=0$ for infinitely many values of $x>0$.

I do not know how to progress with this one.Can someone point me in the right direction?Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly 4 is false for any polynomial (except the constant polynomial $0$ I guess). It's easy to see that 1 and 2 are false by making up examples. For instance $f(x) = -x^3 + 1$ eliminates them both. To see that 3 is true, consider $f(0)$ (and use the fact that polynomials are continuous).

Comment: 4 can be true for the constant polynomial $y=0$, but also for infinite series or infinitely-termed polynomials (maclaurin expansion of the cosine function comes to mind).

Answer (score 1):

Given that $c_0 > 0$ then there is a y-intercept above the x-axis.
Given that $c_n <0$ (negative lead coefficient) then the polynomial gets more and more negative as $x\to\infty$.  Thus, the polynomial must cross the x-axis at some point along the positive x-axis.  Then, for some unknown value $x>0$, we have $f(x)=0$ (this is called a root or zero).  Option 3 is true.

Because $f(x)$ grows more negative as $x$ grows more positive,, option 1 is immediately eliminated.

Unless we are dealing with a constant function $f(x)=0$, or an infinite polynomial $n\to\infty$, then option four is also out of the question.

Because there is a positive y-intercept and polynomials are continuous, there must be at least one sub-interval in which option 2 is false.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ f(x) = 1\!-\!x\:$ refutes $\,1,2,4.\:$ $\,3\,$ is true by the [Intermediate Value Theorem:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) note $\rm\,c_n < 0\,$ $\Rightarrow$  $\rm\,f(+\infty) = -\infty  < \color{#C00}0 < f(0),\,$ so $\rm\,f(x) = \color{#C00}0\,$ for some $\rm\,x\in (0,+\infty)\ $ (polynomials are continuous)